# clear values on exit in android

Tags: java, android

i have some static integer variables in my android application.I am testing the application in emulator.When i click back and return to homescreen and launch the application again, the previous values still persist and new values are added to it instead of overriding.So what is the procedure to clear these values when i close the application. I have tried with `onRestart()` and `onStop()` methods and reset the counter but it dint work.

How do i overcome this issue

Comment: Can you post some of your code here for us to look at it to find problem?

Answer (score 3):

In the `onResume()` you can call an `init()` method, for example :

```
void init()
{
myStaticVar = 0;
//...
}
```

Comment: @technocrat This is I think the best way to go according to your question. But there is a design question behind: why should these value be static if their lifecycle is tied to the lifecycle of an instance of Activity?